# Difference between wrapping a promise in a function and declaring it inside a variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Often when researching promises I see the following note: 
you should put a promise inside a function so it is not invoked immediately.

So I shouldn't use this

```
var somePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){...});
```

and better use this

```
var somePromise = function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){...});
};
```

Could someone please elaborate in a practical manner what exactly is meant by this advice?

Comment: **In second case**, every time `somePromise()` is called a `new Promise` is returned while **in first case**, `somePromise` is already a `promise`.

Comment: Well it depends a lot on your use case whether you want a promise or a function that returns one (and can be called multiple times).

Comment: Can you give an example of where you saw that note?

Comment: it was a discussion on facebook, code:
    `exports.players = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var model = require('../model/schema');
        model.Player.find({},function(err,players){
            if(!err){
                resolve(players);
            }else{
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });`
answer:
 Promises are executed immediately upon creation so they should in most cases be wrapped in a function

Comment: Yes. Usually you will want to load your (current) players more often than only once at application startup (when the module is required), and to do that you need to put the code that does the loading into a function. (This in fact doesn't have much to do with promises in particular, it's true for any code that computes something from global state).

Comment: originally i had this module only required when it is needed, but as I learned its bad practice the way I did. `require('get').players.then(...)`

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to it: either you create a promise immediately or you create a function that will create and return a promise when it is invoked:

#### Create a promise

```
var somePromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){...});
```

Here you have created a promise in the current context which is stored in the `somePromise` variable. You can now use that promise.

#### Create a function that returns a promise

```
var somePromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

In the second case `somePromise` is not a promise but a function. You will have to invoke that function and capture its return value (the promise) to manipulate a promise. No promise is created at this time.

Here is how you would get a promise from calling your function:

```
var myPromise = somePromise(); // myPromise contains the returned promise
```

In the second case you may want to pass arguments to your `somePromise` function making it more versatile and reusable.